# How to refactor SingleLiveEvent<Unit> the best way?

Tags: android, kotlin, kotlin-flow

I have a Kotlin project in which we use the SingleLiveEvent class. In some cases (e.g. to trigger a navigation to another fragment) we use this class with an object type of Unit. I would like to refactor this by using a MutableSharedFlow.

So this is where I come from:

In ViewModel class:

```
val trigger = SingleLiveEvent<Unit>()
...
trigger.call()
```

In Fragment class:

```
viewModel.trigger.observe(viewLifecycleOwner, testObserver)
...
private val testObserver = Observer<Unit> {
   // Perform navigation to another fragment
}
```

Now for the new implementation

In ViewModel class:

```
fun MutableSharedFlow<Unit>.call() = tryEmit(Unit)

private var _trigger = MutableSharedFlow<Unit>()
val trigger = _trigger.asSharedFlow()
...
_trigger.call()
```

In Fragment class:

```
override fun onViewCreated(view: View, savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
    super.onViewCreated(view, savedInstanceState)
    viewLifecycleOwner.lifecycleScope.launch {
        viewLifecycleOwner.repeatOnLifecycle(Lifecycle.State.STARTED) {
            launch {
                viewModel.trigger.collect {
                    // Perform the navigation to another fragment..
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

What I see is that the navigation is not triggered. My question is why that is?

Who can help me out with this one? Any help is greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A `SharedFlow<Unit>` is not suitable for once-consumed events.

Here's what's wrong with your current code. You created your shared flow with the default `replay` value of 0. So if `_trigger.call()` happens before the Fragment begins collecting the Flow, then the value is never emitted to any collectors.

But, if you use `replay = 1` for your SharedFlow, then your Event can get replayed multiple times. Your coroutine is using `repeatOnLifecycle`, so collection will begin again every time the lifecycle reaches that stage again and every time the fragment is recreated. For instance, if you navigate to another fragment in your collect block, and then the user backs up to this fragment again, it will immediately collect that event again and repeat the navigation to the other fragment.

You could build a slightly more robust, but still flawed version of this using a Channel-backed hot flow. A Channel ensures each of its emissions is consumed only once, but it is still [at risk of dropping events](https://github.com/Kotlin/kotlinx.coroutines/issues/2886) if the coroutine currently collecting it is cancelled while an event is in-flight.

A robust way to do it would be creating a SharedFlow with a replay of 1 and that uses EventWrapper as its type, from [this article](https://medium.com/androiddevelopers/livedata-with-snackbar-navigation-and-other-events-the-singleliveevent-case-ac2622673150). This article came from Google, but they have since changed their recommended guidance because they now more strongly emphasize unidirectional data flow (partially because of Compose). See [this article](https://medium.com/androiddevelopers/viewmodel-one-off-event-antipatterns-16a1da869b95) their discussion of the issue and recommended alternative strategy.

Comment: Thank you very much for you detailed answer. It all boils down to reduce the event that I need to trigger to state, as explained in the last article you mentioned.
Using a state property helped me in solving the issue and better understanding.